# Supposedly vs supposed to be

Tags: grammar

> That is supposedly/supposably wrong

or

> That is supposed to be wrong

Which is correct?

Comment: What is the context? What are you trying to convey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"this is *supposably* wrong" means (at least to my ear) "it is just barely possible that this is wrong", whereas "this is *supposedly* wrong" or "this is supposed to wrong" means that "it is generally thought that this is wrong".

A complication with *supposedly* is that it sometimes is used to mean "as commonly but **falsely** believed", and the first dictionary.com definition that I cite below would have us believe that this is the most common meaning of *supposedly*. That has been neither my experience nor that of other lexicographers. The merriam-webster.com definition cited below does not even mention this "common fallacy" meaning.

*supposably* cannot have this "common fallacy" meaning.

See [definition of supposable](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/supposable#:%7E:text=1.,WordNet%203.0%2C%20Farlex%20clipart%20collection.), [definition of supposedly](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/supposedly) and [another definition of supposedly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supposedly)

In the vast majority of cases, people using the word *supposably* in a context like OP's really mean *supposedly*.